# Time Helpers Information Design Tool 4.0

Tags: business-objects

How can I make a time helper in Business Objects Information Design Tool 4.0 that returns

- last 12 months from the current month
- last 13 months from the current month

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement a combination of a parameter and a list of values which calculates the months that interest you.  You can then reference the parameter in a filter which can be used by your end users; a "Time Helper" filter if you will.

First, create a list of values (LOV) in your data foundation:

The implementation will depend on your underlying database, and also what type and format you want your months to appear in.  An example for an Oracle database which brings back a simple string with MMYYYY:

```
select to_char(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, (level - 13)), 'MMYYYY')
  from dual
  connect by level <= 26
```

Second, create a parameter, also in your data foundation, which uses this LOV as the associated list of values.

Third, create a filter in your business layer which references the parameter in a @Prompt.  When the filter is added to a report, the end user will be prompted with the list of possible month values.